# How can a popup window be created in Chrome right after startup, without any website already open?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, website, popups

Recently, when I open up Chrome browser, an annoying scamming site called "stoprobot.site" will pop up for no apparent reason.

AFAIK popups should always be initiated by some website that's already open, but **in my case there is none**. The popup window just comes out of nowhere, usually a minute or so after starting up Chrome. The only thing open is Chrome's default homepage.

**How can this happen?**

I checked my "On startup" settings and it seems perfectly normal, being set to "open new tab".

I tried blocking "stoprobot.site", and now the same thing happens with "stoprobot.fun". Apperently something in the background is generating these stuff.

This happens very randomly so I cannot reliably reproduce the process. But I can study the popup tab once it's open.

**Is there any way that I could somehow track down where this popup tab is coming from?**

(I'm a programmer but I'm not very familiar with web development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably done by a rogue extension that you have installed.

You may check this by opening Chrome in Incognito mode, where
extensions are disabled.
If the popup doesn't appear, then it's verified that the problem is
an extension.

Enter the page `chrome://extensions/` and find the likely extension.
If you don't know which one, you may disable extensions until the
problem disappears, then remove that extension and re-enable the
ones that you have disabled.

I would also suggest to run a deep antivirus scan on the computer.